# Update specific value in JSON file with python

Tags: python, json

I Have problem with update my JSON file form python script.
My JSON file":

```
{"domains": 
    [
        {"name": "example1.com", "type": "mail", "category": "good", "count": 0}, 
        {"name": "example1.com", "type": "mail", "category": "bad"}, 
        {"name": "exampless.com", "type": "mail", "category": "good", "count": 13}
    ]
}
```

I try update "count", but only where "name" is specific

I try this code:

```
def redJSONlist(filename)
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data

def updateJSONdata(data, filename)
    filename.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, filename)
    filename.truncate()

l = redJSONlist("data.json")
for i in l['domains']:
    if(i['name'] == "exampless.com"):
        ile = i['count']
        i['count'] = ile + 1
        updateJSONdata(l, "data.json")
```

I got error:
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'**

Comment: "filename.seek(0)" what do you expect that to do?

Comment: You declared the function passing `filename` as a parameter ->
`def updateJSONdata(data, filename)`.

When calling the function `updateJSONdata(l, "data.json")` you passed a string as an argument.

Comment: If i comment this line, "filename.seek(0)" i got another error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: How Can I modify value of "count" when "name" is specific? Re-write file with new value?

Answer (score 0):

`.seek` and `.write` are methods of a file object, but you are trying to call them on the string type, which results in an error.

What are you trying to achieve by `.seek(0)?` -  if it's to set the file reading on the first byte, it is not needed, python does it automatically on opening

You are probably searching for something like this:

```py
data = {"abc" : "efg"}
filename = "data.json"
with open(filename) as file:
  file.write(data)
  print(type(file))
  print(type(filename))
```

the prints will help you understand the difference between file and filename types

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems:

1. You lack a colon `:` at the end of your function definitions: `def updateJSONdata(data, filename)`
2. The `filename` variable is of `string` type, but you try to call `.seek(0)` on it, which is a method for files. What you need to actually do in the `updateJSONdata` function is to open the file with the given `filename`, run `json.dump` and close it. The following snippet should works:

```
def updateJSONdata(data, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as file: # the "w" option opens the file in write mode
        json.dump(data, file)
```

Note that the `with` block will do the resource cleanup (file closing) for you.

I have include a resource in Python file handling for you to further refer: [Python file handling](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter8_file_io.html)